# Keyboard shortcut for writing a function in another function

Tags: notepad++, keyboard-shortcuts, atom-editor

I don't really know how to word this question on Google so I couldn't find the result.

What I want to know is the keyboard shortcut for putting a function in another function.

e.g.

I'm coding and I type a function:

mathEquation(x)

then I realize I want to wrap that function with another function so it becomes:

Math.floor(mathEquation(x)).

What I am doing now:

1. Type mathEquation(x)
2. Type Math.floor() in front of mathEquation(x) so it becomes Math.floor() mathEquation(x)
3. Cut mathEquation(x) and paste into Math.floor() so it becomes Math.floor(mathEquation(x))

This is really time-consuming and I've seen many Youtube videos where they use some kind of keyboard shortcut to do this really fast.

Comment: Stop typing at `Math.floor(`, hit End, and type `)`.

Comment: Can you elaborate what this question has to do with Notepad++ or Atom?

Comment: I'm looking for the keyboard shortcut in those 2 editors